# Can I clear all but certain attributes from a model?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have quite a number of attributes in my model, and under certain circumstances will need to clear all attributes but 2 or 3. Will this require looping through all attributes? Storing those 2–3 attributes temporarily, clearing the model, then adding them back in? Or is there an easier way to pull this off?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The lazy approach is to use the clear() function and re-add the particular values.

If you have (or may have in the future) events listing on changes, the events are unnecessarily fired.

Take a look at the clear function:

```
clear: function(options) {
  var attrs = {};
  for (var key in this.attributes) attrs[key] = void 0;
  return this.set(attrs, _.extend({}, options, {unset: true}));
},
```

It's not hard, to adapt this to a custom clear() function:

```
var myModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
  // You may also override the Backbone clear function
  partialClear: function(options, keep) {
    var attrs = {};
    for (var key in this.attributes) 
      if (!_.contains(keep, key)) attrs[key] = void 0;
    return this.set(attrs, _.extend({}, options, {unset: true}));
  },
});
```

Then run partialClear with an array of values to keep:

```
this.partialClear({}, ['id', 'a', 'b']);
```